# Can Mac have more than one client using its desktop?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, vnc

I have one Server Mac OSX and have 5 windows PC's in my team.

So I have this program on the MAC but I want two users in my team to be able to use this program, is there any way more than one person can VNC or remote desktop or something to the MAC server?
Then those two users could both use the program on the mac server.

I would need two legal licenses, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple simultaneous GUI sessions are possible using a third-party VNC server.  This page describes the procedure for [Vine Server (OSXvnc)](http://www.testplant.com/products/vine_viewer/multidesktop).  Although it mentions Tiger, these steps work on Leopard as well.  As for the clients, Leopard's built in "Screen Sharing" is based on VNC, but it cannot connect to third-party servers. You will need separate client software as well (e.g. [Chicken of the VNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/))

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using [Aqua Connect](http://www.aquaconnect.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Apple "fixed" this problem in Mac OS X Lion, to be released July 2011. All you will need to do is enable screen sharing in System Preferences (make sure to set a password, and allow access for the desired user accounts), and a VNC client such as Terminals or TightVNC on the Windows machines.

Answer (score -1):

No you can't.

> Our Aqua Connect Terminal Server product. **It is not currently available, but you can fill out this form to be notified when it is ready.**"

Comment: They seem quite willing to distribute their beta to people with a good use for it. A friend's company is using this to run a large group of users on a few Xserves.